# Missing ID causes unexpected behavior in Rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application with some unexpected behavior in one of my views. Applying an id to one of my anchor tags causes that tag to completely fail to render on my website, but removing that id leads to it showing up fine. This id isn't present anywhere in my stylesheets; I just use it for a tiny bit of javascript that has nothing to do with appearance. So I don't know why adding or removing the id would cause any appearance changes.

What could be causing this behavior? I suspect it has something to do with my assets, since I noticed it happening after I recently set up Capistrano to deploy my app.

Comment: That might be related to the template engine. Provide some examples on how that happens and how that does not.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by how to provide examples. But here's the relevant code block.

`<a id="sponsor_link" [...]>Text</a>`

And removing `id="sponsor_link"` causes the tag to work fine.

Comment: I mean snippets from your views. To the question, please. Keep the question self-explanatory so others don't have to read the comments to get the idea.

Comment: I see. So you're using ERB. That blows my initial theory away.

Comment: Have you inspected the underlying markup? Are you sure it was not just rendered invisible, rather than not rendered at all?

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity--yes, it's all just ERB. Yes, I've been playing around with it in Chrome's inspector. I can't find any attributes that might be causing it to not appear to the viewer. The tag appears in the html, but I'm stumped as to why it might not display.

Comment: My co-developers just told me it actually displays on their laptops--so now I'm even more stumped. I've refreshed my cache, used incognito, and tried it on IE--I have no idea what could cause the disparity.

Comment: Apologies for the answer--I slapped myself when I realized the problem. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it wasn't an asset problem at all--apparently AdBlock filters the "sponsor_link" id (the one I was using) completely from the page. I've changed the id and all is good.